# failed to launch Openstack instance: 'authentication required' when trying to create port

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm trying to deploy Openstack Icehouse on Ubuntu Server 14.04 by following the official document. But after Keystone\Nova\Neutron\Glance were deployed, when I tried to launch a CirrOS instance by

> nova boot -nic ... -image ... -flavor ...

, it failed.

The log in **Nova client** shows that:

- **The Neutron client**(Yes, it's neutron. I guess there are interactions between them in booting) tried to connect with Neutron server to create a port on tenant's network.
- But Neutron client set up the token-getting request using **{username:neutron, password:REDACTED}** to Keystone server and used that token to request for creating port to Neutron server.
- Finally, the Neutron Server decided that that's an authentication problem.

I'm sure that I requested to create instance using **tenant 'demo'**'s info($OS_TENANT_NAME, $OS_USERNAME, $OS_PASSWORD, $OS_AUTH_URL were properly set with 'demo''s value) by

> source demoopenrc.sh

with demo's credential in that file.

Is that something wrong in the Neutron client's configuration or booting process? I paste a part of the `neutron.conf` here:

the Keystone setting

```
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_uri = http://controller:5000
auth_host = controller
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol = http
admin_tenant_name = service
admin_user = neutron
admin_password = neutronpass
signing_dir = $state_path/keystone-signing
```

Since the Neutron client used 'neutron' user's credential for token getting, is there something wrong in this part?

Comment: Did the nova command finish successfully? Run the nova command with the '--debug' flag and paste the output in the question

Comment: @Barak Nova command finish successfully, I think. There was no error reported, except at the last step it fetched the instance state and found there was error in that instance. The error info was in nova client's log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved after nearly a month. For anyone still interested in this problem, please visit [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118080406/ask.openstack.org/en/question/47495/authentication-required-when-creating-port-on-demo-net/)